# Get directory of class definition in php

Tags: php

I know about `dirname(__FILE__)`, which returns the directory of the script that calls the function. Is there a way to get the directory of where the class that is returned with `get_called_class()` is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php):

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
print dirname($reflector->getFileName()));
```

(this won't work for internal classes :)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. What are internal classes? Are they similar to what javascript calls inner classes? I thought php didn't do that!

Comment: I meant core classes, like ReflectionClass :)

Comment: Cool, I had no idea ReflectionClasses existed. They seem quite useful, thanks!